# Fragment layout is not getting refreshed properly after rotating device

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have used four tabs in my layout with PagerView. When I launch the application & on the first fragment if I rotate the device it works perfectly fine. Like the attached image.

[image]

The issue occurs when I switch from tab1 to tab3 and after that I rotate the device. Here the tab3 fragment layout is refreshed properly, but if I switch back to tab1 fragment then the layout doesn't change properly. Check the following image for the issue.

[image]